# Project Reactor: Infinite (never ending) Flux

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I've created a publisher using Flux.create method. Other thread pushes data to the FluxSink, data gets transformed and sent to messaging system. This Flux needs to be around as long as application works.
Here is code:

```
public MyClass {
  private final FluxSink<Request> requestsSink;
  private final Flux<Request> flux;

  MyClass() {
    this.flux = Flux.<Request>create(sink -> this.requestsSink = sink)
            .bufferTimeout(props.getMaxSize(), props.getMaxTime())
            .flatMap(this::mergeRequests)
            .flatMap(
                req ->
                    remoteApi
                        .getData(req)
                        .onErrorResume(t -> Mono.empty()))
            .doOnNext(this::sendToTopic)
            .onErrorResume(
                t -> {
                  log.warn("error", t);
                  return Flux.empty();
                })
            .subscribe();
  }

  public void pushData(Request request) {
    requestsSink.next(request);
  }

  ... other methods
}
```

So, I don't care if error happens somewhere in Flux, I just want to log it and continue processing other entries.

For some reason, this flux get's disposed under unknown circumstances (isDisposed returns true). This happens under high load.

- How to prevent flux from cancelling/disposing/finishing?
- What are conditions under which flux can be cancelled/disposed/finished?
- How can I debug/log the flow to understand what's the reason for cancelling/disposal?

Comment: you want to manually push data through a Flux that will call a seemingly imperative `sendToTopic`... Maybe that's a sign that you don't really need Flux? what or who invokes `pushData` method on `MyClass`?

Comment: I need flux because of buffering functionality it provides. pushData is called whenever listener receives message from another topic (Kafka)

Comment: I read in multiple stackoverflow answers that escaping the sink from the flux.create lambda is not recommended/nogo (although I'm still searching for the reason why it is not) and that using processors is the recommended thing to do. Did you solve your problem ? Maybe using processors will solve it ?

Comment: Hi @jonenst. What problem do you have and what operations are you executing on your flux? I was getting some sort of exception, but cannot remember right now that was it. The problem was around buffer or/and group operation and flatMapping those

Comment: FluxBufferTimeout has "requested" field inside. it's getting decremented on each emit I believe. In my case it was set to 0 eventually and caused "Could not emit buffer due to lack of requests". Setting both concurrency and prefetch to Integer.MAX_VALUE in flatMap helped me. At least that's what I remember.

Comment: Have you tried using a processor? https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#processor-overview

Comment: @BogdanKobylynskyi I've tried EmitterProcessor and it indeed looks better style-wise. Thanks for the tip.